Computing the divisor class group of toric varieties over an arbitrary field
Let $k$ be an arbitrary field and let $X$ be a toric variety over $k$, coming from a fan $\Sigma$. If $k$ is algebraically closed, then theorem 4.1.3 of Cox ,Little and Schenck’s Toric Varieties book says that there is an exact sequence
$M\rightarrow \mathrm{Div}_T(X)\rightarrow \mathrm{Cl}(X)\rightarrow 0$.The first map sends every $m\in M$ to $\mathrm{div}(\chi^{m})$ and the second map sends every torus-invariant Weil divisor on $X$ to its class in $\mathrm{Cl}(X)$.This exact sequence allows for the convenient computations of divisor class groups of toric varieties coming from a fan, defined over an algebraically closed field.
I am wondering whether the same exact sequence works over an arbitrary base field $k$, so that similar computations work in this generality.
When I look at the proof of theorem 4.1.3 in the book mentioned above, it says that $\mathbb{C}[x_1^{\pm 1},x_2^{\pm 1},…,x_n^{\pm 1}]$ is the coordinate ring of the torus $(\mathbb{C}^{*})^n$, which is isomorphic to the coordinate ring $\mathbb{C}[M]$ of the torus $T_N$. But over an arbitrary field $k$, the $n$-dimensional algebraic torus is not always isomorphic to $(\mathbb{G}_m)^n$.

The torus $T$ may have non-trivial Picard group. Therefore this sequence is not exact in general. One may consider for example $T: x^2 + y^2 = 1$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. The closure of this is a conic, and $T$ is isomorphic to the projective line with a closed point of degree two removed. Hence in this case $\mathrm{Pic}(T) \cong \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ and the boundary divisors only generate a subgroup of index $2$ in the full Picard group.
However all is not lost and one can write down an analogous sequence using Galois cohomology. I assume for simplicity that $X$ is a smooth and proper  toric variety for some torus $T$ over $k$ and that $k$ is perfect with absolute Galois group $\Gamma_k$. Then the sequence
$$0 \to M\rightarrow \mathrm{Div}_T(X_{\bar{k}})\rightarrow \mathrm{Cl}(X_{\bar{k}})\rightarrow 0$$
is exact. Applying Galois cohomology, one obtains
$$0 \to M^{\Gamma_k} \rightarrow \mathrm{Div}_T(X_{\bar{k}})^{\Gamma_k} \rightarrow \mathrm{Cl}(X_{\bar{k}})^{\Gamma_k} \rightarrow H^1(k,M) \rightarrow H^1(k,\mathrm{Div}_T(X_{\bar{k}})).$$
We have $\mathrm{Cl}(X_{\bar{k}})^{\Gamma_k} = \mathrm{Cl}(X)$ since $X(k) \neq \emptyset$. Moreover by Shapiro's Lemma and $H^1(k,\mathbb{Z}) = 0$, one sees that $H^1(k,\mathrm{Div}_T(X_{\bar{k}})) = 0$ since $\mathrm{Div}_T(X_{\bar{k}})$ is a finitely generated free $\mathbb{Z}$-module which is a permutation module for $\Gamma_k$. Moreover an application of the Hochshild-Serre spectral sequence shows that $H^1(k,M) = \mathrm{Pic}(T)$ (see Lemma 6.3 of [1]). Altogether one obtains the sequence
$$0 \to M^{\Gamma_k} \rightarrow \mathrm{Div}_T(X_{\bar{k}})^{\Gamma_k} \rightarrow \mathrm{Cl}(X) \rightarrow \mathrm{Pic}(T) \rightarrow 0,$$
so the failure of exactness comes precisely from $\mathrm{Pic}(T)$.
[1] Sansuc, J.-J. Groupe de Brauer et arithmétique des groupes algébriques linéaires sur un corps de nombres. J. reine angew. Math. 327 (1981), 12--80.

Thank you so much for your detailed answer. If the torus is split, is the sequence $M\rightarrow \mathrm{Div}_T(X)\rightarrow \mathrm{Cl}(X)\rightarrow 0$ exact?

Yes this is true. Firstly we always have $\mathrm{Div}T(X{\bar{k}})^{\Gamma_k} = \mathrm{Div}_T(X)$. Then if $X$ is split then the Galois action on $M$ is trivial and obviously $\mathrm{Pic}(T)$ is also trivial. The one thing which is not clear to me is whether $T$ being split implies that the Galois action on the boundary divisors is trivial.

Thank you so much for your kind help and detailed solution.

Thank you very much for your kind reminder. I would like to ask, if the torus is not split, how should I compute the divisor class group of the toric variety? Thanks.

The exact sequence I wrote down gives a fairly complete description of the divisor class group. As $\mathrm{Pic}(T)$ is finite, the exact sequence I wrote down shows that the boundary divisors generate a finite index subgroup of the divisor class group. For many applications this is sufficient. There can naturally be relations between this divisors, but for example in the anisotropic case (where $M^{\Gamma_k} = 0$) there are no relations.

Thank you so much for your detailed help.
