Is the torus of any affine, simplicial toric variety always split?
Let $k$ be an arbitrary field and $X$ be an affine, simplicial toric variety over $k$ of dimension $n$. Then $X$ has the form $\operatorname{Spec}(k[\sigma^{\vee}\cap\mathbb{Z}^n])$ for some $n$-dimensional simplicial cone $\sigma$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.From Cox, Little and Schenck’s book Toric Varieties, if the torus of $X$ is split, then I can compute the divisor class group of $X$ by the exact sequence $M\rightarrow \rm{Div}_T(X)\rightarrow Cl(X)\rightarrow 0$.
I am trying to compute the divisor class group of $X$ in the general case that $k$ is any field.Is the torus of $X$ always split? If not, how to compute the divisor class group of $X$?

I don't understand the question – in your situation, the torus is $T={\rm Spec}(k[\mathbb{Z}^n])\simeq \mathbb{G}^n_m$ which is split.

But there is a similar local description of neutral affine toric varieties (i.e. the torus is an actual torus as opposed to a torsor under a torus), using toric monoids together with a $\operatorname{Gal}(\bar k/k)$-action. Then everything picks up a Galois action, and there might be a way to formulate this question in that generality.

Thank you so much for your insights and kind help .

I think that the Weil restriction of affine space (viewed as a split toric variety) with respect to a finite field extension should be a counter-example

In any case this looks like almost a duplicate of your previously asked question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/477119/computing-the-divisor-class-group-of-toric-varieties-over-an-arbitrary-field/477249#477249

I would like to ask why the torus for an affine, simplicial toric variety is always $\operatorname{Spec}(k[\mathbb{Z}^n])$?

As already mentioned, a counter example is given by the Weil restriction. In your notation, let $K/K$ be a finite Galois extension of number fields and consider the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$ of $K$ viewed as a module for $\mathrm{Gal}(K/k)$. This is free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank $[K:k]$ (it is the induced representation of $\mathbb{Z}$). Then $\mathrm{Spec( k[\mathcal{O}_K])}$ is an affine simplicial toric variety, but not split. The corresponding torus is the Weil restriction of $\mathbb{G}_m$ with respect to $K/k$.

Thank you very much for your kind help.
